# Pandas percentrank based on groups within each index

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, percentile

I have a dataframe, with a index which has dates (there are multiple same dates). For each date there are columns such as Price, Score, Category etc....

I want 1 new column in the dataframe called pctrank.

In the pctrank column, I want to calculate the percentile rank within each Category for each index level based on the Score values. Eg, for 1/24/2007 in below data, I would do a percent rank of all the scores of the supermarkets, and separately percent rank of all the score for all Reteraunts for that date, and then move to next date.

As data set is large I would like it to be reasonable efficient.

** EXAMPLE DATA BELOW **

Subset of df:

```
            Category    SCORE
1/24/2017   SuperMarket 12
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  21
1/24/2017   SuperMarket 13
1/24/2017   SuperMarket 22
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  27
1/24/2017   SuperMarket 30
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  34
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  32
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  21
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  12
1/24/2017   Bar         10
1/24/2017   Bar          3
1/24/2017   Bar         24
1/25/2017   Resteraunt  32
1/25/2017   Resteraunt  63
1/25/2017   Resteraunt  32
1/25/2017   Bar         12
1/25/2017   Bar         32
1/25/2017   Hospital    22
1/25/2017   Hospital    12
1/25/2017   Bar         10
```

Example output:

```
            Category    SCORE   Percnt rank    
1/24/2017   SuperMarket 12         0    
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  21         0.2  
1/24/2017   SuperMarket 13        0.333 
1/24/2017   SuperMarket 22        0.666  
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  27       0.6   
1/24/2017   SuperMarket 30         1    
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  34         1    
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  32       0.8   
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  21       0.2    
1/24/2017   Resteraunt  12       0  
1/24/2017   Bar         10       0.5    
1/24/2017   Bar          3       0   
1/24/2017   Bar         24       1  
1/25/2017   Resteraunt  32       0  
1/25/2017   Resteraunt  63       1  
1/25/2017   Resteraunt  32       0  
1/25/2017   Bar         12      0.5 
1/25/2017   Bar         32       1  
1/25/2017   Hospital    22      1   
1/25/2017   Hospital    12      0   
1/25/2017   Bar         10     0
```

Real data set has loads of dates and corresponding entries.

Comment: I think output for `Resteraunt`  for first `date - 1/24/2017` is wrong - there is 5 unique values, I think this is typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) divide by [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) - for starts from `0` is necessary substract `1`:

```
df['Percnt rank'] = df.reset_index() \
                      .groupby(['index','Category'])['SCORE'] \
                      .apply(lambda x: (x.rank(method='dense') - 1) / (x.nunique() - 1) ) \
                      .values
print (df)

              Category  SCORE  Percnt rank
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     12     0.000000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     21     0.250000
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     13     0.333333
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     22     0.666667
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     27     0.500000
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     30     1.000000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     34     1.000000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     32     0.750000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     21     0.250000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     12     0.000000
1/24/2017          Bar     10     0.500000
1/24/2017          Bar      3     0.000000
1/24/2017          Bar     24     1.000000
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     32     0.000000
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     63     1.000000
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     32     0.000000
1/25/2017          Bar     12     0.500000
1/25/2017          Bar     32     1.000000
1/25/2017     Hospital     22     1.000000
1/25/2017     Hospital     12     0.000000
1/25/2017          Bar     10     0.000000
```

Becasue if use default `rank`, output is different:

```
df['Percnt rank'] = df.reset_index()\
                      .groupby(['index','Category'])['SCORE'].rank(method='dense', pct=True)\
                      .values
print (df)
              Category  SCORE  Percnt rank
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     12     0.250000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     21     0.333333
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     13     0.500000
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     22     0.750000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     27     0.500000
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     30     1.000000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     34     0.833333
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     32     0.666667
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     21     0.333333
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     12     0.166667
1/24/2017          Bar     10     0.666667
1/24/2017          Bar      3     0.333333
1/24/2017          Bar     24     1.000000
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     32     0.333333
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     63     0.666667
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     32     0.333333
1/25/2017          Bar     12     0.666667
1/25/2017          Bar     32     1.000000
1/25/2017     Hospital     22     1.000000
1/25/2017     Hospital     12     0.500000
1/25/2017          Bar     10     0.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

using a custom function I calculate `rank(method='dense', pct=True)` excluding the smallest value, then fill it back in with `0`

```
def prank(s):
    mask = s.values != s.values.min()
    r = pd.Series(index=s.index)
    r.loc[mask] = s.loc[mask].rank(method='dense', pct=True)
    return r.fillna(0)


df.assign(**{'Percent rank': df.reset_index().groupby(['index', 'Category']).SCORE.apply(prank).values})

              Category  SCORE  Percent rank
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     12      0.000000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     21      0.200000
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     13      0.333333
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     22      0.666667
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     27      0.400000
1/24/2017  SuperMarket     30      1.000000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     34      0.800000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     32      0.600000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     21      0.200000
1/24/2017   Resteraunt     12      0.000000
1/24/2017          Bar     10      0.500000
1/24/2017          Bar      3      0.000000
1/24/2017          Bar     24      1.000000
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     32      0.000000
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     63      1.000000
1/25/2017   Resteraunt     32      0.500000
1/25/2017          Bar     12      0.500000
1/25/2017          Bar     32      1.000000
1/25/2017     Hospital     22      1.000000
1/25/2017     Hospital     12      0.000000
1/25/2017          Bar     10      0.000000
```